# Paypal express checkout button

Tags: javascript, paypal, dom-events, express-checkout

I am integrating Paypal express checkout button on my site and I have the following code:

```
paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment
    style: {
        size: 'medium',
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'rect'
    },

    payment: function(resolve, reject) {
           
        var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://example.com/create-payment';
            
        paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_UR)
            .then(function(data) { 
                resolve(data.paymentID); 
            })
            .catch(function(err) { 
                reject(err); 
            });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data) {
    
        // Note: you can display a confirmation page before executing
        
        var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://example.com/execute-payment';

        paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            payerID: data.payerID,
        })      
            .then(function(data) { /* Go to a success page */ })
            .catch(function(err) { /* Go to an error page */ });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

I want to set the `payment` and `onAuthorize` separately. Is there any way to do it?

Something like: `paypal.Button.onAuthorize = function() { };`

Answer (score 1):

You can create the functions separately, if it helps

```
function payment() {
   ...
}

function onAuthorize() {
   ...
}

paypal.Button.render({

    payment: payment,
    onAuthorize: onAuthorize

});
```